# How to enable more file formats for GZIP/Deflate Compression

Tags: optimization, webserver, compression, gzip

I enabled gzip/Deflate compression on our servers per Google's Page Speed directives, and it looks like it's now compression html/php files, but a couple file formats aren't being compressed that Google rightfully is saying should be compressed, namely .js and .ttf files. How do I add more file formats to httpd.conf so they're compressed as well?

Current lines in httpd.conf I have are:

```
#
# Deflate output configuration
#
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Is it as simple as adding text/js and text/ttf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. Just add more types:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/x-font-ttf
```

Comment: Thanks. I added those, restarted apache, and Google still complains that a .js file and .ttf files aren't gZipped.

Comment: If you use Firebug you should be able to see if it is compressed or not. Check that to see if this is working or not. Also, while testing, I would use htaccess for this. Then once you're sure it is working properly update your http.conf file with the final content. It will be faster for you to test that way.

Comment: Where in Firebug will I see if the ttf and js a deflated?

Comment: In the "Net" tab look for a ttf file and click on it. You'll see the headers. If you see "Content-Encoding gzip" it is compressed.

Comment: The .js files are being in fact showing in Firebug as gzipped. Google's analysis is just flawed?

I can't check in Firebug the ttf's though, as Firefox loads the .woff font files instead.

Comment: Are you using the Google Firebug Pagespeed tool? Or some other tool? When I use the pagespeed tool I find I sometimes have to do a hard refresh to get fresh results.

Comment: No, I'm using the Online validator at https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/

Comment: It's very possible it's not retrieving fresh content from your site. You could try again later or try the Firebug plugin instead if you want better results.

Comment: I've found that `application/x-javascript` and `application/javascript` often need to be added in `mime.conf`

Comment: Another good (and very simple) place to test is http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/ - useful as external verification.